# Что за IP вида 10.658941?

Tags: сеть, ip, tcp-ip

```
ping 10.658941
```

Даёт такой IP:

> PING 10.658941 (10.10.13.253) 56(84) bytes of data.

Объясните, пожалуйста, что значит `.658941`, и почему именно в таком формате? И для чего вообще это нужно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ip - это 32-х разрядное число. На 4 байта его делят, грубо говоря, для разделения уровня сетей, а выводят с разделением точками - для удобства восприятия.

```
 10.13.253 = 10*256*256 + 13*256 + 253 = 658941
```

Можно вообще весь адрес записать как `168431101` или `0x0A0A0DFD`